# Create Azure Service Fabric on-premise cluster in Linux

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have .NET Core Azure Service Fabric application and I want to deploy it to my 
Ubuntu Linux server.

There is tutorial for Windows Server Deployment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server

There is also tutorial for Azure Linux deployment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-vnet-and-linux-cluster

Is it possible to run ASF on-premise on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-anywhere#create-service-fabric-standalone-clusters-on-premises-or-with-any-cloud-provider):

> Standalone clusters currently aren't supported for Linux. Linux is supported on one-box for development and Azure Linux multi-machine clusters.

and

> **Supported operating systems for standalone clusters**
>
> You are able to create clusters on VMs or computers running these operating systems **(Linux is not yet supported)**:
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 2018, Service Fabric for Linux is available on-premises through BOSH. See:

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2018/12/04/announcing-service-fabric-provider-bosh/

https://starkandwayne.com/blog/deploying-microsoft-service-fabric-via-bosh/

https://github.com/starkandwayne/service-fabric-boshrelease

Below is copied from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/deploy-service-fabric-ubuntu-clusters-on-premises-using-bosh/ :

Service Fabric integration with Bosh provides the following:

- Define and deploy infrastructure necessary for Service Fabric on any environment including on-premise (VMWare) and the three major public clouds (Azure, GCP, AWS)
- Define and deploy Service Fabric Ubuntu clusters on any environment
- Perform zero-downtime rolling upgrades of Service Fabric and the OS
- Monitor health of the infrastructure and reattach any downed VMs or disks back to the cluster
- Fully open source and collaboration to shape the future of this release is welcome!